# Why won't my Canon 400D/XTi turn on/off properly?

Tags: troubleshooting, battery, canon-400d

My camera is a Canon 400D (digital rebel XTi). It sat on a shelf for quite some time.

When I insert a (newly charged) battery, the camera doesn't switch on. I get this screen:

[image: back of camera, showing settings/controls]

and switching the camera on/off doesn't do anything.  Without a lens mounted, I get this screen, and I can't turn off the camera; I have to remove the battery to turn the camera off.

Before this problem appeared I replaced the clock battery with a new one, but I'm not sure that it caused this problem.

Comment: The statement: "Problem with P mode (Canon 400D) only in off status and indicator of switch on doesn't work" doesn't make sense. What is "off status?" What do you mean by "indicator of switch on doesn't work?" What lens do you have on the camera? Try taking it off and reattaching it.

Comment: I have made it a lot of times

Comment: And when lens isn't  set, I get this screen, and I can't switching off camera, only when I taking off a battery camera is switching off

Comment: Does your camera work as expected when the mode dial is turned to other exposure modes before turning on the camera?

Answer (score 3):

The battery icon on the display says it all: your battery is very weak, a fully charged battery should be shown full.

If this is the same battery that sat on the shelf for quite some time, try with a new one (off-brand ones do work and are not that expensive). Li-Ion batteries self-discharge and when they get fully-discharged [plenty of problems arise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164103/if-li-ion-battery-is-deeply-discharged-is-it-harmful-for-it-to-remain-in-this-s).

PS: personally, I have recently revived a 450D that sat abandoned for over 5 years. Worked well... with new batteries.

Comment: But I have same screen when my camera is off

Comment: Camera "off" isn't really a power switch, but a signal to the processor to go in low-power mode. If their isn't enough power in the camera it could not be able to sense it.