# My Canon 400D won't power up properly - stuck screen!

Tags: canon

Just seen this post - [Why won't my Canon 400D/XTi turn on/off properly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124852/why-wont-my-canon-400d-xti-turn-on-off-properly). I have EXACTLY the same problem with my old Canon 400D. Even bought a new battery (charged it fully) and replaced the CR016 (date/time 3v cell). Switching on produces the same unusable (stuck) screen - nothing controllable, all buttons inactive etc. Tried taking batteries out, lens off, CF card out and leaving for 24hrs.  Then load it up again and switch on - nothing but this same [image: stuck screen]screen after about 20 secs! Is there a solution to this? Has anyone solved this? HELP!

It could be an expensive door-stop!

Comment: The XTi/400D usually sells for about $50 so it’s not very expensive to replace.

Comment: Is it working for 20 secs, then freezes, like windows? Or is it like this immediately after startup?